# Definition of exponential family and entropy

Tags: entropy, exponential-family

I'm reading *Graphical Models, Exponential Families, and Variational Inference* [[pdf]](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewainwrig/Papers/WaiJor08_FTML.pdf) by Wainwright and Jordan.

They define (p. 39) an exponential family by its derivative
$$ p_\theta(x) = \exp \{ \langle \theta, \phi(x) \rangle - A(\theta) \} $$
with respect to a measure $\nu$.

My first question is the missing factor of $h(x)$. I figured it was absorbed into the measure $\nu$, so that
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}\nu}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} = h(x) $$
with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.

The definition (p. 38) they give for entropy is
$$ - \int p(x) \log p(x) \nu (\mathrm{d} x),$$

But then this doesn't seem like the usual definition of entropy
\begin{align}
\text{book's entropy} &= - \int p(x) \log p(x) \nu (\mathrm{d} x) \\
&=  - \int p(x) \log p(x) h(x) \lambda (\mathrm{d} x) \\
&\neq - \int p(x) h(x) \log \left( p(x) h(x) \right) \lambda (\mathrm{d} x) \\
&= \text{usual entropy}
\end{align}

What gives?

Comment: Uh? I see no issue since $p(x)\nu(\text dx)=p(x)h(x)\lambda(\text dx)$

Comment: @Xi'an: edited to clarify